# Barcode lines are unequal in python barcode generator

Tags: python, image, image-processing, line, barcode

[image: This is my output below:]

[image: This is expected]

Sometimes these unequal lines appears in my image. Why is that so? They are not that visible though, but it seems quite odd.

```
codee=str(code)
EAN = barcode.get_barcode_class('ean8')
ean = EAN(codee, writer=ImageWriter())
imag = ean.save('barcode')
```

Comment: send this problem to author of this module.

Comment: yes, this might help!